# Adobe AIR - Create screenshot of the app and share it (actionscript)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

How can I create a simple screenshot of the stage and share it with social (facebook, whatsapp, etc.)

Now my code is:

```
var screenshot:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var screenImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
screenImage.draw(this.stage);
screenImage.encode(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768), new JPEGEncoderOptions(90), screenshot);

var localFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("bild.jpg");
var fileAccess:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileAccess.open(localFile, FileMode.WRITE);
fileAccess.writeBytes(screenshot, 0, screenshot.length);
fileAccess.close();
```

This code generate a jpg of the stage. How can I share or send this file?
P.s. I use AnimateCC.

Thx.

Comment: It's not easy. For each social network you need a respective ANE (AIR Native Extension) that supports **at least** logging in into your social network account **and** sharing content. Given all that, it is possible that ANE does not allow posting images directly and you need your own server to store images first (e.g. this ANE allows sharing images via links but probably not directly: http://myflashlab.github.io/asdoc/com/myflashlab/air/extensions/fb/package-detail.html)

Comment: Hi Daniele, welcome to Stackoverflow!   You're getting a lot of close votes for your question (and I may add to that).  Here are some tips to make your question clearer.  - Have a clear problem statement - right now your problem is not specific and very broad - which makes it difficult to answer in short, succinct way.   It's also good to show what you've tried - this gives people a good starting point to answer your question and usually helps with identifying the problem.    From your example code, it looks like you're not actually having a problem getting a screenshot?  or are you?

Comment: If your problem is actually just with the social sharing, then again, post what you've tried so people have a starting point in answering and update your question to make the problem as clear as you can.  What is the expected behavior vs. what is or isn't happening with your current code. If you're using libraries or other third party code, mention them and if applicable link to them.   All these things will help you get a good answer to your question and make it a question that will benefit others to come.

Comment: Yes, the code generates a screenshot, but I don't know how to share the file now.
I use only Adobe AnimateCC. No external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To share a file using AIR on Android you have two main options, both utilise AIR Native Extensions (ANE) and I don't believe it is possible on Android (or iOS) without them.

1. (easy) use an ANE that launches an Intent with the image file data;
2. (hard) use an ANE that implements the sharing destination SDK. This may require user login and other more complex integrations.

There are several ANEs that implement the first method including the [Share ANE](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Share) that I developed. To use this ANE you would use the following code:

```
Share.service.shareFile( localFile.nativePath, "bild.jpg", "image/jpeg" );
```